# make my site responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on this [site](http://www.iombeachhuts.com/) and trying to make the site mobile-responsive.But when I'm trying in responsive mode I see a white space to the right of the screen .I don't know from where its coming from.Can anybody take a look and help me.I have tried adding this to the css

```
body{
width :100%;
}
```

but no way its helping. This is my [site](http://www.iombeachhuts.com/)  Please help!! Thanks!!

Comment: Your logo and your footer text are not responsive, i.e. their width is fixed.

Comment: @creimers is correct. You also don't need `width:100%` on the body

Comment: am i missing something!!, where is white space on the right??

Comment: footer .container{ width: 100%; }

Comment: @Manjuboyz - you need to make your screen size < 768px to see it

Comment: ah, thanks @martin, for anyone who  not understand about above as me, just use ctrl+shift +M in Firefox it shows the different resolution screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add/edit your css as accordingly

```
footer .container {
max-width: 960px;
}

.logo {
background: url(../img/layout/logo1.png) no-repeat;
height: 58px;
max-width: 531px;
display: block;
margin: 45px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
background-size: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
   body {
      padding-right: 0px; 
      padding-left: 0px; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's this section of your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

Change the left and right padding to 0. It's in the `bootstrap-responsive` CSS file though so I'd avoid editing that file and create a rule to override it in your own CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @media (max-width: 767px)
    body {
     padding-right: 20px; 
     padding-left: 20px; 
    }
```

This code is (probably) on line 784 in your *bootstrap-responsive.css* file and adds the padding on that screen size.

Add in your main.css this:

```
   @media (max-width: 767px){
      body {
        padding-right: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px; 
      }
   }
```

The white space would be gone.
You can remove the lines in *bootstrap-responsive.css* too, but I prefer to do changes in your own files and let plugin files unedited.

Hope this helps!